# What is $dE/dR$ and how does when $dE/dR=0$ makes electrical field intensity maximum?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, intensity

[image]

Actually my question is that when $dE/dr=0$ then $dE$ also comes out to be zero then how does electric field intensity maximum when $dE/dr=0$. And also I don't understand that how does this value came out ($r= ± a/\sqrt2$). I mean I want the step by step procedure for this derivation.

Comment: Without you showing any work there is no realistic way for someone to help you. This forum does not support “do my homework” type of questions.

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: you want me to attach full concept related to this?

Comment: @MattHanson that's a bit of an exaggeration. pretty easy to see what the text is doing here.

Comment: I just mean that the OP gave no indication that they had made any effort at actually solving the problem or giving indication of what specific part of the derivation was giving them trouble. I confess that I was a little frustrated when I wrote the comment, so it probably came across too strongly.

Answer (score 2):

The textbook is trying to find the [maximal electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum), which is done by taking the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the electric field with respect to time and finding the $r$ such that $\mathrm{d}E/\mathrm{d}r=0$ (which gives us the [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics))). What happens next is that the electric field has some dependence on $r$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}r}\sim\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r}\left[\frac{r}{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}}\right]=0$$
Then by applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to the argument in the square brace, we obtain,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}r}\sim\left[\frac{1}{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{r^2}{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^{5/2}}\right]=0$$
The equation above can only be zero if the arguments inside the square brace are zero, which means that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}r}\implies\frac{1}{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}}=\frac{r^2}{\left(r^2+a^2\right)^{5/2}}\tag{1}$$
which Eq (1) can now be solved for $r$ in terms of $a$, which is what your book finds with $r=a/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: See the image i attached …… the answer is coming something else than this…..plz correct me

Comment: Please someone answer me

Comment: You mean the derivative should be zero, the derivative need not have a minimum value for a function to have an extremum (ex: $f(x)=x^2$ has a global minimum but the derivative has no extrema).

Comment: @Physicsstudent this is the answer. There isn't anything more to it: the textbook is using [global optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) to find the [maximal electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum). This is done by taking the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the electric field with respect to time and finding the $r$ such that $\mathrm{d}E/\mathrm{d}r=0$. This is what I explained above as well.